# Writing a letter for galley proof

Tags: publications, paper-submission, communication

My first paper is accepted for publication in a journal and I
received its galley proof. The galley proof needs no corrections.
Is there any good letter for responding to the journal?

Comment: Does this journal not follow an automated online system where you can directly (correct and) submit the recommendation?

Comment: Good question Ali.

Answer (score 7):

Don't overthink this.  Just say what you have to say.

> Thank you for sending the proofs.  I have read them and no corrections are needed.  Sincerely, Ali.

Comment: It was useful for me! Thanks